# VBScript User input variable

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript

I am creating a script to split csv files up, I want to let the user input the interval in which the files are split into new ones.

The problem I am having is that when I input the interval it isn't splitting, but yet if I hard code the value in it does split.

```
Option Explicit

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Dim objFSO, objInputFile, objOutputFile
Dim intLine, intFile
Dim strHeaders
Dim strInputFile, strOutputPrefix, strLine
Dim MyDate
Dim userSplit
Dim split

'strInputFile = InputBox("Enter file location")
strInputFile = "H:\VBS\domS_CUST.csv"
strOutputPrefix = strInputFile & DatePart("yyyy", Now) & "-" & DatePart("m", Now) & "-" & DatePart("d", Now) 


intFile = 1
intLine = 0

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objInputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strInputFile, ForReading)

If (objInputFile.AtEndOfStream = True) Then
  ' The file is empty
  WScript.Quit 1
End If

strHeaders = objInputFile.ReadLine

userSplit = InputBox("Enter when you want to split")

Do While (objInputFile.AtEndOfStream = False)

split = userSplit

  strLine = objInputFile.ReadLine

  If (intLine <= 0) Then
    Set objOutputFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strOutputPrefix & "_" & intFile & ".csv", True)
    objOutputFile.WriteLine strHeaders

    intLine = 1
  End If

  objOutputFile.WriteLine strLine


  If (intLine >= split) Then
    objOutputFile.Close
    Set objOutputFile = Nothing

    intFile = intFile + 1
    intLine = 0
  Else
    intLine = intLine + 1
  End If
Loop
```

The input is this line:

```
userSplit = InputBox("Enter when you want to split")
```

And I cannot seem to get it to split at the value of this, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: have you considered [casting](http://www.pctools.com/guides/scripting/id/200/?act=reference) your string expression to a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an `On Error Resume Next` in your code that you didn't show, otherwise the line

```
split = userSplit
```

would've raised the error

> Illegal Assignment: 'split'

`split` is the name of a built-in function, so it cannot be used as a variable name. It's also completely unnecessary, because you could simply use `userSplit` without assigning its value to another variable.

---

**Correction:** As Ekkehard.Horner pointed out in the comments, the `Dim split` supersedes the built-in function definition, thus no error is raised.

---

However, the main reason why your code doesn't work as you expect is that the `InputBox` function returns a string value. To make the comparison with `intLine` work correctly, you need to convert the string to an integer or long integer:

```
userSplit = CLng(InputBox("Enter when you want to split"))
...
If (intLine >= userSplit) Then
```

And you should at least add a check to handle situations where the user pressed "Cancel":

```
userSplit = CLng(InputBox("Enter when you want to split"))
If userSplit <= 0 Then WScript.Quit 1
```

Also, by using the the [`Line`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chsfhd43%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property, your code could be simplified to this:

```
filename = "H:\VBS\domS_CUST.csv"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set infile = fso.OpenTextFile(filename)

prefix  = fso.BuildPath(fso.GetParentFolderName(filename) _
  , fso.GetBaseName(filename) & "_" & Year(Now) & "-" _
  & Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & "-" & Right("0" & Day(Now), 2) & "_")

userSplit = CLng(InputBox("Enter when you want to split"))
If userSplit <= 0 Then WScript.Quit 1

Do Until infile.AtEndOfStream
  If infile.Line = 1 Then
    headers = infile.ReadLine
  Else
    If (infile.Line - 2) Mod userSplit = 0 Then
      If infile.Line > 2 Then outfile.Close
      Set outfile = fso.CreateTextFile _
        (prefix & (infile.Line - 2) \ userSplit + 1 & ".csv", True)
      outfile.WriteLine headers
    End If
    outfile.WriteLine infile.ReadLine
  End If
Loop
outfile.Close
```

Comment: Very nice 'refactoring' (+1). Just one nit to pick: If you `Dim split` (as Nathan did), VBScript will accept `split = ...`.